# Conflict with unicode-math and listings

Tags: listings, unicode-math, fancyvrb

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}
\lstset{fancyvrb}
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
\pm 
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

This is the minimal code. And I get the error "Improper alphabetic constant".

PS: I need `\lstset{fancyvrb}`.

Comment: A warm welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 5):

`\pm` is internally defined as "the character ±". In the listings code `\pm` is used in an \lccode assigment but its value is much too large. You can avoid the problem by converting `\pm` to a macro. This is handled differently by listings. E.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\AtBeginDocument{%
 \let\ORIpm\pm
 \renewcommand\pm{\ORIpm}}

\begin{document}


\lstset{fancyvrb}
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
\pm
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```